# Time slots using Case in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm trying to sum on fields by 3 time slots with this code:

```
SELECT 
CASE when TIME(v.time) between cast('00:00:00' as time) and cast('06:00:00' as time) then '00:00:00 - 06:00:00'
when TIME(v.time) between cast('06:00:00' as time) and cast('16:00:00' as time) then '06:00:00 - 16:00:00'
when TIME(v.time) between cast('16:00:00' as time) and cast('00:00:00' as time) then '16:00:00 - 00:00:00' End as 'TimeSlot',
sum(v.resting)
FROM vital_activity_histogram v
GROUP BY 'TimeSlot'
```

The result I want is(for example):

```
time slot              | Sum(v.resting)
00:00:00 - 06:00:00        24
06:00:00 - 16:00:00        56
16:00:00 - 00:00:00        72
```

what I get when I run the query is:

```
time slot              | Sum(v.resting)
00:00:00 - 06:00:00        24
```

And I have data inside the other time slots.
Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!!

Comment: Just a tip, you can do "case TIME(v.time) when between cast... when between... end", i.e. you don't have to specify TIME(v.time) more than once. (At least in ANSI SQL....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY TimeSlot`, not `GROUP BY 'TimeSlot'`: as things stand you're grouping on a string literal, which is constant (and therefore every record is in the same group).

See also [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)